# Web push notification with Image

Tags: javascript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I have a web app and I sent a notification on Firebase dashboard with image but It didn't displaying with image. Firstly my code it was.

```
const getMessage = () => {
        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging.onMessage(async (message) => {
            if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
                if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
                    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(async (reg) => {
                        if (reg) {
                            await reg.showNotification(message.notification.title, {
                                body: message.notification.body,
                                image: message.notification.image
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    await Notification.requestPermission();
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

I tried like this;

```
const getMessage = () => {
        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging.onMessage(async (message) => {
            if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
                if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
                    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(async (reg) => {
                        if (reg) {
                            const image = await fetch(message.notification.image).then((r) => r.blob());
                            await reg.showNotification(message.notification.title, {
                                body: message.notification.body,
                                icon: URL.createObjectURL(image)
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    await Notification.requestPermission();
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

but it didn't work

Notification is look like this;

[image: My notification]

What should I do.

Comment: What is the format of the image? Some formats like [SVG may not be supported](https://blog.pushpad.xyz/2017/06/can-i-use-svg-images-inside-web-push-notifications/). Try with PNG or JPG.

Comment: @collimarco Hi thanks for answers This notification is displaying chrome in Windows but its doesn't display in macOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed use PWA.

I deleted 'disable: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'. ' in my next.config.js

Thanks for all answers I will close this question.

Answer (score -1):

Service Worker registration may not be done correctly. Before this code, you can manually register the Service Worker by using the `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` function. Can you try?

Comment: Notification is displayed without picture whether there is a picture or not. I thing service worker is working correctly

Answer (score -1):

You are using the **icon** feature to show an **image**, but this feature should only be used for a favicon or a small icon to display on a mobile device screen. For picture notifications, you need to use the image feature. correct use of the first code block. you need to check if you are getting the image url correctly. Make sure you have specified `message.notification.image` correctly and that it is accessible.

---

If url is correct check below steps.

**Image size:** The maximum supported image size for Firebase image notifications is 1MB. So make sure the size of the image you are sending is less than 1MB.

**CORS:** Note that if the image URL is hosted on a different server than the Firebase server, the image server must comply with CORS policies. Otherwise, the image cannot be uploaded by Firebase and displayed in the notification. Check the image server's CORS policies and edit if necessary.

**Permissions:** Make sure your browser's notification and image permissions are set correctly. In some browsers, special permissions may be required for picture notifications. For example, in the Chrome browser, you need to grant "Push notifications" and "Notifications" permissions for picture notifications.

**Browser compatibility:** Firebase picture notifications may not be supported by some browsers and operating systems. So, check if the browser and device you sent your notification to are supported.

Comment: I tried all your comment. They is look like suitable in my app I changed icon to image but didn't work thanks for your answer. I using firefox developer edition.